# ontology Modeling and interrogation

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, protege

Good Day
In my ontology I have concepts (Students, course, Time) where Students are instantiated with (student1 and student2) course with (English, french, etc..) Time with instance of time T1 and T2. then I have relation have-course between (student1, student2 and English course). and I have relations start-at between course and time (between English and T1 and T2). 
I want to know how may do in order to have this sentence (Student1 have-course English that start-at T1) and (Student2 have-course English that start-at T2). 
because I want to know with SQWRL query when Student1 start his English course. 
I think that the relation start-at should not between course and Time only, but it should be with the student also. 
I don't succeed in this 
Help please
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi unfortunately I never worked with this SQWRL but here is my try how it could work:

student(?s)^haveCourse(?s,?c)^startAt(?c,T1)-> sqwrl:select(?s)

This query should get you a list of students that have courses starting at T1

Comment: Thanks for your response. what I need is to select  the Time when StudentX start his course. what I know in input is the name of course (english course) and the name of Students. and what I want in the output is the Time. ok let me explain more for example I want to know all students when start their english course. with this query: Students(?x)^haveCourse(?x,?c)^startat(?c,?t)->sqwrl:select(?x,?t)--> this query give a combination of result for example student1->T1; Student1->T2; Student2->T1; Student2->T2: which is false :( I hope you understand more my need: Thanks

Comment: is their some bind mechanism in sqwrl? so you can specify that ?s should be Student1 or ?c should be Englisch